# Would sending data continously to a _simple_ server cause an out of memory error?

Tags: java

Given a simple network protocol of "command arg0 arg1 argn\n" as a data stream, if you sent data continuously to such a server, without ever sending a newline, would this cause a denial of service attack, by causing a simple server to error out with an out of memory error?

I'm interested because I've been given a java assignment at uni, that has the network protocol already defined, and it makes no mention of a maximum amount of arguments, or command/argument maximum length.

I'm to create a client and server that abide by this protocol, as well as being resilient against attack, but the lack of maximum message size is really eating at me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would it cause an out of memory error?

Potentially, yes.

A simple server is likely to try and read the entire line into a `StringBuffer` before splitting it into a command and arguments.  (For example, this is what `BufferedReader.readLine()` or `Scanner.nextLine()` will do.)  That `StringBuffer` could get big enough to fill the heap.  (The maximum size of a `StringBuffer` is `2^31` chars ... and the space usage can be up to double that temporarily.)

Even if the server is a bit more careful, it can still get into problems if it needs to have all the arguments (for a normal command) before it can start processing the command.  And if you (somehow) dealt with that, consider the possibility that the command name or a single argument is `~2^31` characters long.

The only realistic way to defeat these potential DOS attacks is to put a defensive limit on the length of a request message.

---

> I'm interested because I've been given a java assignment at uni ...

... yea well you are probably over-thinking it, unless there is a written requirement that your solution be resilient against denial of service attacks.  Remember, this is an Exercise ... not a requirement to build a real production strength system.

If you were producing a *real* system, you would discuss this issue with the "client" and work out a way to deal with it; e.g. modify the protocol specification to include a message length limit.

Answer (score 1):

No it don't.Even if the protocol is waiting for a new line to process data there is some buffers at many levels. For example, if your server is not reading your data fast enough, it's TCP receive buffer will be full and it's OS will begin to stop sending you back acknowledgments packets which will in turn block your calls to `write`.

That is for network layer. But if your server implementation is keeping the total String in memory, it may lead to `OutOfMemoryError` but a good implementation may be protected from that.

Comment: "a good implementation" what would be good methods to protect from this? or even detect that it is happening?

Comment: Avoid using `readLine`, discarding data and returning an error when the arguments are too long.

Comment: So no real way to do it without setting an arbitrary limit(which isn't stated in the spec), considering that the commands are unlikely to be able to start processing without all the arguments.